# Cannot install Nuget Package HelpPage in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, cors

My problem is as follows. I've tried to install the latest version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage.5.2.3` but I always get *"Install failed. Rolling back"*

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional and WebAPI 2.2 with .NET Framework 4.5. I've searched for solutions to fixed the problem but nothing helped. I can't start my API using HTTP Requests. When I installed `EnableCors` I got the problem.

Here's the error message:

> ..\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs(14,18,14,42): error CS0535: 'WebApi.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetDocumentation(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor)'.
>
> ..\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs(14,18,14,42): error CS0535: 'WebApi.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member  'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetResponseDocumentation(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor)'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when upgrading to WebAPI 2.1 XmlDocumentationProvider does not implement interface member GetDocumentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295078/error-when-upgrading-to-webapi-2-1-xmldocumentationprovider-does-not-implement-i)

Comment: @Tom I've tried the solution of this thread but I've still the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. I'm approached as follows:

Firstly I've opened a command prompt and navigated to the following path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv` then I typed the command `regsvr32 VsLangproj.olb`. Here is a helpful thread https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3609

Afterwards I've managed the nuget packages when you go on `TOOLS -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for project maps` and updated the following packages:

> ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET Razor 3.2.3 ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 Client Libraries 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 Core Libraries 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 Cross-Origin-Support 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 HelpPage 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 Tracing 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 Web Host 5.2.3
>
> ASP.NET WebPages 3.2.3

Thirdly I've configured the following lines in the root Web.config of the WebAPI Project.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

And the last change was in the Views/Web.config of the project:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Here I've changed the Version of Razor from 2.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0 and now the API runs without problems! This thread was very helpful [Site stopped working in asp.net System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941053/site-stopped-working-in-asp-net-system-web-webpages-razor-configuration-hostsect)

Here is an exactly description how to update the MVC4 to MVC5:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I hope the post is helpful for other users.