# Async controller doesn't work in upgraded project from MVC 3 to MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded all stuff using [Upgrading a project to MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495781/upgrading-a-project-to-mvc-5) but method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    [...]
    return View(model);
}
```

Gives me results like:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]
```

instead of normal view.