# Using Glass Mapper's @inherits GlassView<T> with MVC 5.0 views

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

I recently updated my solution to MVC 5 and I am facing the following issue.

It appears as though I can no longer format the code in any of my Views that utilize `@inherits GlassView<T>`. By format, I mean auto-formatting using the `CTRL + K + D` key combination. When I press the format combination, the namespace and class name get lowercased and all references to `Model` appear to break. This only occurs on GlassViews... traditional Views using a `@model` declaration appear to be unaffected.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051550/razor-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-vs-2012-with-mvc-5

Comment: Could be that you need to a bindings redirect because Glass is compiled against an earlier version of the MVC framework