# view does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage' in sitecore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

in my application i have a view where i giving ViewModel Name that time it's giving an error on console as: 
   MyViewName does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'

i'm giving ViewModelName as

```
 @using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc;
 @using DncMvc5.ViewModels.Venues
 @inherits GlassView<GetVenuesViewModel>
```

here i'm not able to bind my ViewModel data collection to view.
can anyone help me to figure out this issue

Comment: This may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923281/using-glass-mappers-inherits-glassviewt-with-mvc-5-0-views

Comment: when i remove Model then i have not any issue but when i use this getting an error on console

Answer (score 0):

Please check you assembly binding redirects and ensure that you have the correct Glass MVC version for your solution. This normally solves the problem.