# Razor works in my project but not recognised when coding

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem concerning Razor in my ASP.NET MVC4 project. As I'm using Razor for my views, it appears as it's not recognised by visual studio. All my razors' tag are in black as shown below:

[image]

Everything works when I'm launching the app so the references should work an I get any errors.
Any idea ?

Comment: Post your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: Posting his code as text wouldn't help because he was trying to point out how the Razor syntax isn't being color-coded. Posting as text wouldn't show that.

Comment: @Hubert, what is your file's extension?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and MVC are you using?

Comment: @CraigW. Exactly what i wanted to show. My file extension is .cshtml :)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and MVC4

Comment: As i could read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051550/razor-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-vs-2012-with-mvc-5   The problem concerns an update of visual studio 2012, will see after the download, I will keep you informed !

Answer (score 0):

So as an answer of my previous question, downloading the ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 solved my problem. All my razor' tags are correctly highlighted and works fine. 
I past again the link for that download.
Thanks for all.

[Download ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)