# Extension method that exactly matches required arguments "has some invalid arguments"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, razor, intellisense, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I've recently started work on an MVC 5 application, and have run into a head-scratcher regarding intellisense in my Razor views. I think this image sums up the problem quite well (apologies for tiny size, please right click and open in new tab or read transcript below):

[image]

For those of you who can't see this clearly, my invocation of `Html.ActionLink("Create new", "Create")`, results in the IDE complaining about the following:

> `'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'` does not contain a definition for `ActionLink`, and the best extension method overload `'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)'` has some invalid arguments

But clearly, if I pass two strings to an extension method of `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`, this exactly matches the required signature `{{extensionmethod}}(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)'`. What is the problem here?

Oddly enough this is only affecting Intellisense; the view compiles and runs just fine. I found a few [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051550/razor-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-vs-2012-with-mvc-5) that suggest Visual Studio 2012 (which I am using) has trouble with Razor 3 intellisense. The accepted solution is to install [Web Tools 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx), which I've already done. Restarting the IDE showed no difference.