# Razor syntax highlighting not working in VS 2012 after installing with MVC 5

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm playing around with MVC 5 RC 1 in Visual Studio 2013 RC. Works very well.

Now I upgraded an existing MVC 4 project in VS 2012 to MVC 5 the same way as described here

Any known workaround or ideas to get highlighting back?

Comment: Did you try restarting VS?

Comment: yes, i try but still it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Razor syntax highlighting not working in VS 2012 with MVC 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051550/razor-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-vs-2012-with-mvc-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft released a new version of ASP.NET Web Tools for VS 2012. After installing syntax highlighting is back again.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Installing VS 2012 Update 4 was not enough.

Comment: Downloaded the installer from this link. But when tried to install, it says "Microsoft Web platform installer couldn't find the product you tried to install..."