# Intellisense not working after upgrading Umbraco version

Tags: umbraco, upgrade, versioning, umbraco7

I am working on the Umbraco CMS.
I have recently upgraded my project from umbraco version 7.1.3 to 7.3.0.
It works fine. But now, Intellisense is not working in Visual Studio 2012 but it works in Visual Studio 2013 perfect.

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue? I have tried this [Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-rc#13076629) but it not works.

Please help me out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my intellisense issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051550/razor-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-vs-2012-with-mvc-5#20068345).

I have just installed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx) and it work fine for VS 2012.

Comment: Can you mark this as answering your own question please? That way it improves the quality of SO overall :-) thanks!