# What version of Visual Studio do I need for ASP NET MVC5?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

What version of Visual Studio do I need to create ASP NET MVC5 project?

2013? update x? 2015 CPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2013** or  **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web**

In Visual Studio 2012 you can run ASP.NET MVC5, but installing something before.  Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20102311/7720

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 installed and I can't find reference to RazorEngine 3.0.0.0. Is then the RazorEngine 3.0.0.0 part of ASP.NET MVC5?