# Cannot find Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace in MVC 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I've installed the ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 as directed in this post:
[How do I install ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102831/how-to-install-asp-net-mvc-5-in-visual-studio-2012)

I have started a new Mvc 5 project, but I can't find the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace or dll. I've checked all the packages under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack 5\Packages and it's not there either. From the MSDN website it seemed as if it should be already included in Mvc 5 if you look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.mvc(v=vs.118).aspx

Is it only included in VS 2013 or is there something else I must install?

Comment: What do you mean by *but I can't find the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace or dll*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll for MVC 5 from this nuget package (MVC5Futures)... https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/ (NOTE: ASP.NET MVC Futures includes unsupported prototype features for ASP.NET MVC, from the MVC team)

P.S. There are other versions of the futures pack available that support other versions of MVC, e.g. MVC4Futures https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc4Futures/

Comment: Thank you, I thought it may only be available in the futures package. Is it worth installing if it's unsupported?

Comment: @Erika I would say, as ever, it depends on what you intend to build with it, e.g. if you build some security feature which is later found to have a gaping flaw, MS wont fix it, will the futures team fix it?... however that's not to say that the whole thing is unsupported, indeed only some of it will be... I'm afraid it's a decision only you can make.

Answer (score -8):

May be because what you are looking for is `System.Web.Mvc` ?

Comment: As he said in his first post : "I can't find the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace or dll" which is normal since it doesn't exists. That's why I'm suggesting to use System.Web.Mvc which is probably what he is looking for.

Comment: It's 2 different packages. He is looking for the futures package. Delete the answer and your rep will come back up.