# This product requires Microsoft visual studio express 2012 for web

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, installation

I want to write WebAPI2 and MVC5 in Visual Studio 2012. Install VS2012, but I can not build WebAPI2 and MVC5 project. So find [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102831/how-do-i-install-asp-net-mvc-5-in-visual-studio-2012) tell me to install ：

1. Windows 8.1 SDK
2. Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
3. ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012

But when I install "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012", have some error message :

> This product requires Microsoft visual studio express 2012 for web,please install Microsoft visual studio express 2012 for web. then try installing this product again.

[image]

How can I fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: Hi, please try to download this tool from https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids, then install it to test.

Comment: @kyoko, could you create/build the specific web app in your VS now?