# Attempt by 'System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dependencies

My application was working fine and after I did some upgrades I am getting this error.

> #### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> Attempt by security transparent method '`System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()`' to access security critical method '`System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()`' failed.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: `System.MethodAccessException`: Attempt by security transparent method '`System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()`' to access security critical method '`System.Web.WebPages.Razor.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()`' failed.
>
> **Source Error**: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Version Information**: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET      Version:4.0.30319.18055

I cannot remember the updates I did. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I **need** to run MVC 3 to reproduce [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412740/writing-excel-using-epplus-not-workable-after-deployed) but all the answers are useless because they only tell me to upgrade.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I think the issue has been solved, but if not, use this package from Nuget:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.0.0
```

I have wasted a day for this error but this single line has done the work for me

Comment: NOTE: instead of hard-coding the version (in the `install-package` command), just install the latest version that is >= 5.0.0

Comment: I already have the lates asp.net mvc and still getting the error. Solution must be something else.

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7' already exists in project 'Web\SomeProjectName'

Answer (score 13):

tried . . . `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.0.0`

and. . . `Install-Package -Id  Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers`

both with no success, finally had to update all packages via nuget. . worked!!

http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/202082-ASP-net-MVC-Error-before-application-start

> If you're using visual studio open the nuget packages windows and run
>   Update-Package, this will update all your dll to the last version. If
>   it still not work, see this page:
>   http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: worked for me, plus accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949676/razor-2-to-razor-3-mvc-5

Answer (score 11):

I got this error when deploying a site where Mvc had been upgraded from 4 to 5 but I had not updated web.config.

Changing from this:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

to this:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: Needed to do your answer above after doing the accepted answer: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.0.0`

Answer (score 6):

For me also same error occured. 
It was fixed by installing the NuGet package

```
  Install-Package -Id  Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
```

Comment: My code was not previously using WebHelpers, so I saw no reason to add it now.  However, adding it made my project work!  Go figure!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by based on the article [Updating Razor 2.0 to 3.0 with Asp.net MVC by by Anthony Fassett](http://anthonyfassett.blogspot.no/2013/11/updating-razor-20-to-30-with-aspnet-mvc.html)

The following block of code was missing from my Web.Config:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: This was missing in my case too.
I just added these line with the correct version 5.2.7.0

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was an incompatibility issue. I had theses pacakges:

- `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` version 4.x
- `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`, version 3.x

I suppose that upgrading `Mvc` to 5.x would have worked, but I needed to keep `Mvc` 4.x, so i had to downgrade `Razor` and `Mvc` to 2.x. To do so, you just have to install the older version, like this:

```
Install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages -version 2.0.30506
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor -Version 2.0.30506
```

After downgrading these packages, the first error disappeared, but there was still another error related to a problem in `web.config`. I had to change the binding redirect for Razor:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" ... />
  <!--bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /-->
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I don't know why, but the binding redirect wasn't updated by the Nuget installation, which should have done it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions for this problem:

- Follow the tutorial on upgrading [your asp.net solution](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)
- Don't forget to remove the Microsoft-Web-Helpers dll and install the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Then, make sure you have upgraded all your nuget Packages (use "Upgrade-Package") and check your dll's in web.config.

The error is probably an action in an old DLL, when you are converting your project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a nuget installation had changed my Web.Config:

```
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

`newVersion="1.1.0.0"`** should be **`newVersion="5.1.0.0"`**

Answer (score 1):

Right Click to Project -> Manage Nuget Packages for solution than find

**Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc** and **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** update latest versions

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by applying the "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" command.

After that I solved my project with Web API.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I upgraded a NuGet package - '**Microsoft.AspNet.Web Pages**' version 3.2.3.  I am using VS2012, starting a new vanilla '**ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application**' with template  '**Internet Application**' using Windows Authentication or Windows Azure authentication.

Perhaps the update is not compatible with other components, and these other components must also be upgraded.  Other answers suggest updating **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc**, **Microsoft.Net.Compilers**, and/or **Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers**.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on **ASP.NET Web API** project and fetch same problem after adding following nuget **CacheCow.Server.EntityTagStore.SqlServer**

It solved installing this one

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Install-Package -Id Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.0.0

This worked for me