# Unknown server error after install visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've installed vs 2013 and I'm getting so many weird errors that it is becoming disturbing.

I do not even know what to think about this error.

Can someone tell me how to overcome this error?

[image]

For a larger screen shot of the error see this link.

http://www.storefrontdoors.net/!/vs-2013-error.png

Comment: This has already been answered here: [Upgrading From MVC4 to MVC5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454852/upgrading-from-mvc4-to-mvc5-pre-release)

Answer (score 1):

### Root cause

Your project is referencing assembly **version 2.0** from GAC (global assembly cache) and after install VS2013 it has been replaced with new assembly **version 3.0** in windows GAC.

### solution.

remove and re-add references to new version in your web app project.

also update your *web.config* find the assembly config under system.web section

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

then correct your assembly version

optional..
binding old assembly version to new one
under web.config runtime section

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- ... -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```