# Trying to upgrade to ASP.NET MVC5 with Web Api 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I've created an ASP.NET MVC4 Project with WebAPI template. It runs fine out of the box.

Now I go to NuGet Package Mgr, and try to UPGRADE to MVC5 and WebApi2.2

This now crashes my website project:

```
             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1144d5e1\eec3db38\assembly\dl3\2e964601\053540f5_e81bd001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
```

trying to follow the answer at this post -

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454852/upgrading-from-mvc4-to-mvc5
```

however I'm still getting the `system.Web.WebPages.Razor.config error` above.

After updating my web.config, under Area\Views, it now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and here's my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.24" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="4.0.30506" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: can you show your route config and your controller?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api Here you can see how web api routing works

Comment: Have you checked your main config (binding redirect), as well as any in areas? ... I'd spin up a new default MVC 5 project and compare the configs.. I've seen this before, but can't recall the fix. :/