# How to use Grouping for DropDownListFor in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to use a Grouping in mvc4. How can I do it with mvc 4 DropDownListFor controls?

Here is a example:

[image]

Here is my real code in .cshtml for DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new List<SelectListItem>{
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Sales/Marketing", Value="Sales/Marketing"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "BPO/Call Center", Value="BPO/Call Center"},                                                                                                      
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Receptionist/Front Office", Value="Receptionist/Front Office"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Cook", Value="Cook"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Aayah/Child Caretaker", Value="Aayah/Child Caretaker"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Gardener", Value="Gardener"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Security/Guard", Value="Security/Guard"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Construction/Laborer", Value="Construction/Laborer"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Garment Tailor/Textile", Value="Garment Tailor/Textile"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Office Helper", Value="Office Helper"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Maid who can Cook", Value="Maid who can Cook"},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Data Entry/Back Office", Value=""}},
                                                   "-- Choose Category --", new { @id = "Country", @class = "form-control", @data_error = "Choose No. of Employees is required", @required = "required" })
```

Even I have try to install **DropDownList Optgroup MVC 1.0.0** but its not able to install on VS2012

My application framework is 4

How can I do this in client side with DropDownListFor use grouping for category?

Comment: How about just making a optgroup from html prepared by the controller? You can always insert list in your view and than use foreach (or two) to fullfill optgroup. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need any nuget packages you can use grouping `SelectListGroup` with `SelectListItem` like this

```
@{
    var group1 = new SelectListGroup() {Name = "German Cars"};
    var group2 = new SelectListGroup() {Name = "Swedish Cars"};
}

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new List<SelectListItem>{
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Audi", Value="Audi",Group =group1},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mercedese", Value="Mercedese",Group =group1},

                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Saab", Value="Saab",Group =group2},
                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text = "Volvo", Value="Volvo",Group =group2}},
                                                   "-- Choose Category --", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

**Edit**

or you can do it manually with looping like this

first create a `class`

```
  public class DropdownData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

then in `action`

```
   ViewBag.Dropdowndata= new List<DropdownData>()
    {
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "German Cars",Id = "Audi",Name = "Audi"},
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "German Cars",Id = "Mercedese",Name = "Mercedese"},
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "Swedish Cars",Id = "Saab",Name = "Saab"},
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "Swedish Cars",Id = "Volvo",Name = "Volvo"},

    };
```

you can also use `ViewModel` instead of `Viewbag`

and finally in view

```
<select name="Category" id="Country" class="form-control" data_error="Choose No. of Employees is required" required="required">
    <option value="">-- Choose Category --</option>
    @{
        string group = null;

        foreach (var groups in (List<DropdownData>) ViewBag.Dropdowndata)
        {
            if (group != groups.GroupName)
            {
                group = groups.GroupName;

                <optgroup label="@group">

                    @foreach (var data in (List<DropdownData>) ViewBag.Dropdowndata)
                    {
                        if (group == data.GroupName)
                        {
                            <option value="@data.Id">@data.Name</option>
                        }
                    }
                </optgroup>
            }
        }
    }


</select>
```

Comment: @Vikas ah my bad give me sometime to update my answer

Comment: sure please take your time

Comment: what if want to use `SelectListGroup` how can i fix this in vs2012

Comment: @Vikas `SelectListGroup`  was introduced in mvc 5.2 i misunderstood the question because you are working on mvc 4

Comment: you can check this link  [How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and [upgrading from MVC4 to MVC5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454852/upgrading-from-mvc4-to-mvc5)

Comment: `SelectListGroup` is short way to do that 2nd one is bit long process to step to do it but i prefer  `SelectListGroup` it help me to in other projects too as well but I finding a way how can i do it vs2012 and i have available framework with my vs2012 is .net 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2 but there is missing `SelectListGroup` still

Comment: can we do this with db `ViewBag.Dropdowndata= new List<DropdownData>()
    {
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "German Cars",Id = "Audi",Name = "Audi"},
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "German Cars",Id = "Mercedese",Name = "Mercedese"},
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "Swedish Cars",Id = "Saab",Name = "Saab"},
        new DropdownData(){GroupName = "Swedish Cars",Id = "Volvo",Name = "Volvo"},

    };`

Comment: @Vikas sorry what do you mean by db

Comment: it okay Usman i have done that simple way will update project some day then will do that ones I have latest visual studio

Comment: @Vikas if my answer helped you can accept my answer :)